# Updating pandas dataframe based on values from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dictionary:

> dict_sex = {'Tom': 'Male', 'Hans': 'Male','Christina':'Female'}

And I would like to update the appropriate values for sex in the pandas dataframe below

```
Name      Sex
Tom
Hans
Christina
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?